# Rotate Alarm Clock hands by touch iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, alarm, rotatetransform

I want to develop alarm clock app, in which user can rotate Hour and Minuit hands of the clock by touch and set the alarm.
How can I achieve that ?
I tried with code in

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
     {
         _imgHand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_imgHand.transform, RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(1));
     }
```

But this is not giving effect that i want. Moving much faster and in one direction only.

How can i move that images according to fingers rotation, clockwise/anticlockwise, and how can I get time with angle of alarm hands.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are only moving the rotation by 1 degree each time, you need to calculate the angle the hand should be at based on the position of the touch

say you have a touch point x,y relative to an origin at the centre of the clock, you can calculate the angle with trigonometry

```
CGFloat angle = atan2(y, x);
_imgHand.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```